# Textarea content with programming code is not inserting in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, codeigniter

I am uploading articles using PHP, article containing the programming source code , when i write the code at the bottom of the article then data is inserting in database. But when i write more than two code e.g one code at the middle of the page and one at the bottom of the page then  **$_POST['description']**  goes to empty.

Here is the screenshot of editor (this will make a sense for you):
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lTEO.png)
.

I am testing also with custom (simple) PHP , the original code is of codeigniter.

Here is the inserting query:

```
mysql_query("insert into articles SET title=>"'.$_POST['title'].'",description="'.$_POST['description'].'" ");
```

For codeigniter case:

```
$data_i  = array('title'=>$_POST['title'],'description'=>$_POST['description']);
        $this->db->insert('articles',$data_i);
```

**This is working fine on WAMP server but it is not working online at hosting server**

Comment: what does this have to do with codeigniter? also you shouldn't use mysql anymore (mysqli or PDO preferred) and you aren't escaping your inputs which might be part of the problem.

Comment: I am testing it also with custom PHP. This project is in codeignter. Problem is on both custom PHP and codeignter .

Comment: #Alex , if we are submitting just the form then also this problem occurs. Even i am not using the $_POST['description']  , so  i think escaping is not the problem. This is working fine on WAMP server but it is not working online at hosting server.

Comment: Well if you are going to tag codeigniter you should also show the CI code otherwise remove the tag. In any case in CI you can `var_dump($_POST['description'])` see if contents are ok there, if they are then you can turn on `db_debug` in database.php and see if it spits out any errors when inserting. In response to your latest comment, whenever you submit the form any inputs (including description) will be submitted, so I'm not sure of your logic regarding that.

Comment: can you post your code which are you talking about?

Comment: Do you mean article code?